# store array filled by .push() in html data attribute as the html is generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

If I store an array in a data attribute like `$('#test1').data('array-test',["one","one","one","one","one"])` or writen in the html like `<div data-array-test='["one","one","one","one","one"]'> </div>` when I call `$('#test1').data('array-test')` I get back an array.

However, if I fill an array using a loop and then add the array into the html as it is being generated like shown below, I get back a string instead of an array. I've commented out some other ways Ive tried too.

**How can I have `retrievedVal2` below returned s an array?**]

Note that in my actual use case the attributes will contain multi-dimensional arrays

```js
var retrievedVal1=$('#test1').data('array-test');

var myArray=[];
for(var i = 0;i<5;i++){
    myArray.push("one");
}
// $('#test2').append('<div id="test3" data-array-test="'+myArray+'"></div>');
// $('#test2').append('<div id="test3" data-array-test=\''+myArray+'\'></div>');
$('#test2').append('<div id="test3" data-array-test=\''+myArray.toString()+'\'></div>');

var retrievedVal2=$('#test3').data('array-test');
// var retrievedVal2=JSON.parse( $('#test3').data('array-test')); // gives "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"


var test;
```

```html
<div id="test1" data-array-test='["one","one","one","one","one"]'></div><br><br>
<div id="test2"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myArray.toString()` generates `one,one,one`. What you need is ["one","one","one"].

Use JSON.stringify(myArray) to create proper string format for the array.

```
$('#test2').append('<div id="test3" data-array-test=\''+JSON.stringify(myArray)+'\'></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that you set a string data for the `data-array-test` attribute (each element does not have any quotes, also the square brackets are missing). So it should be like this:

```
var myArray=[];
for(var i = 0;i<5;i++){
  myArray.push("\"one\"");
}
$('#test2').append('<div id="test3" data-array-test=\'['+myArray.toString()+']\'></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will convert anything that is not valid JSON to a string.  Use JSON.stringify to covert it.  I prefer using appendTo() and then chaining attr() to that:

```
$('<div id="test3"></div>').appendTo($('#test2').attr("data-array-test", JSON.stringify(myArray)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = [];
ids.push(1);
ids.push(2);
$('#element_id').attr('data-ids',JSON.stringify(ids)); // storage
ids = JSON.parse($('#element_id').attr('data-ids').split(",")); // retrivied
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what is going on here. This post has been flagged for low quality.